# "in connector.php line 68 could not find driver"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, database-connection

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL DB from Laravel using CMD Command Interface.

I try to connect it by using the command: `php artisan migrate`.

but it failed to connect and show an error message.
Which I could not understand. Kindly guide or share solution.

I've attached an image that displays an error:

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you but that error message in text, not image.

Comment: Have you installed the PHP-extension for postgres? Is your database configuration in Laravel correct? We need more info or we would need to make wild guesses.

Comment: yes extension is enable

Comment: then restart your wamp or xammp server

Comment: in connector.php line 68 could not find driver

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 php.ini files:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
```

NOTE: This is using my version of PHP and Apache, change to what yours are.

The php.ini file located in the both folders is what you need to update, the extentions:

```php
    extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
    extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

These are what you need to uncomment (remove the ; symbol).
Restart both Wamp and the Command Prompt.

In .env file change driver to

```php
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
```

then hit

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: followed your steps but could not find the solution.